# Dropan() is not working on pandas - nothing is dropped

Tags: pandas

The size of dataframe is not changed after I called dropna. But I want all rows that has one value missing being dropped.

```
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Import data
    census_subdivision_profile = pd.read_csv('../data/augmented/census_subdivision_profile_merged.csv')
    print(census_subdivision_profile.shape)
    census_subdivision_profile.dropna()
    print(census_subdivision_profile.shape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget assign output back:

```
census_subdivision_profile = census_subdivision_profile.dropna()
```

Or add parameter `inplace=True` to [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
census_subdivision_profile.dropna(inplace=True)
```